# create VLAN sub-interfaces automatically if they are part of a bridge in /etc/network/interfaces file

Tags: debian

According to [Debian NetworkConfiguration](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) document *"If you create the VLAN interface only to put it into a bridge, there is no need to define the VLAN interface manually. Just config the bridge, and the VLAN interface will be created automatically when creating the bridge"*. I have a following `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# mgmt network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.10.1.182
        netmask 255.255.255.192
        network 10.10.1.128
        broadcast 10.10.1.191
        gateway 10.10.1.190


# VLAN 100
auto br-VLAN-100
iface br-VLAN-100 inet manual
        bridge_ports eth1.100

# VLAN 200
auto br-VLAN-200
iface br-VLAN-200 inet manual
        bridge_ports eth1.200

# VLAN 300
auto br-VLAN-300
iface br-VLAN-300 inet manual
        bridge_ports eth1.300

# VLAN 400
auto br-VLAN-400
iface br-VLAN-400 inet manual
        bridge_ports eth1.400

# VLAN 500
auto br-VLAN-500
iface br-VLAN-500 inet manual
        bridge_ports eth1.500
```

However, interfaces `eth1.100`, `eth1.200`, `eth1.300`, `eth1.400` and `eth1.500` are not automatically created one I start the system. Do I still need to create those interfaces manually or is there a mistake in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

Comment: Just to make a test: If you infoke `ifup br-VLAN-100` for example, will the bridge and it's vlan members be created? Does this bug only affects you when you stop the `network` service?

Comment: @nwildner If I execute `ifup br-VLAN-100` then I receive an error `interface eth1.100 does not exist!`. However, `br-VLAN-100` interface will be created. This bug(or configuration mistake) affects me if I start the network service.

Comment: Maybe(and i'm just guessing here) Debian is not adding the vlan interface because your `eth1` interface is not up. What about if you add the following lines to just bring `eth1` up without an ip address? `auto eth1`, `iface eth1 inet manual`, `up ip link set dev eth1 up`

Comment: @nwildner I tried with that and `eth1` interface was brought up during the bootup: `3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000`. However, VLAN sub-interfaces `eth1.100`, `eth1.200`, `eth1.300`, `eth1.400` and `eth1.500` were still not created.

Comment: I'm not assuming you are noob, but is the vlan package installed ? (`apt-get install vlan`) . It have all the 802.1q interface creation utilities on Debian.

Comment: @nwildner Once I installed the `vlan` package, the VLAN sub-interfaces defined under the bridge were created automatically. Thanks! I wasn't aware that `vconfig` is required. When I defined VLAN sub-interfaces with `auto eth1.100`, `iface eth1.100 inet manual`, `auto eth1.200`, `iface eth1.200 inet manual`, etc then they were created without `vconfig` utility.

Comment: Glad it worked :)  Posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the `vlan` package, that have the binaries required to configure the interfaces.

To solve this:  `apt-get install vlan`. Installing the `bridge-utils` package is also needed.

**Long explanation:**

You could check out the scripts that lies inside the `vlan` package with the following command:

```
root@host:~# dpkg -L vlan
...snip...
/usr/share/doc/vlan/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/vlan/howto.html
/etc
/etc/network
/etc/network/if-post-down.d
/etc/network/if-post-down.d/vlan
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
...snip...
```

The vlan package adds some scripts that will handle vlan interfaces during te `ifup`.

This is the piece of code that will probe the `eth*.*` and bring it up as 802.1q interfaces: `vim /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan + 18`

```
  eth*.*|bond*.*|wlan*.*|em*.*|p[0-9]*.*)
    vconfig set_name_type DEV_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
    VLANID=`echo $IFACE|sed "s/eth[0-9][0-9]*\.0*//g;s/bond[0-9][0-9]*\.0*//g;s/wlan
[0-9][0-9]*\.0*//g;s/em[0-9][0-9]*\.0*//g;s/p[0-9][0-9]*\(p[0-9][0-9]*\)\?\(_[0-9][0
-9]*\)\?\.0*//g"`
    IF_VLAN_RAW_DEVICE=`echo $IFACE|sed "s/\(eth[0-9][0-9]*\)\..*/\1/;s/\(bond[0-9][0-9]*\)\..*/\1/;s/\(wlan[0-9][0-9]*\)\..*/\1/;s/\(em[0-9][0-9]*\)\..*/\1/;s/\(p[0-9][0-9]*\(p[0-9][0-9]*\)\?\(_[0-9][0-9]*\)\?\)\..*/\1/"`
  ;;
```

However, this will only explain how debian probes interfaces from `/etc/network/interfaces`. We have to go deeper. Taking a look at the scripts the package bridge-utils have(`dpkg -L bridge-utils`) we will find one that is of our interest: `vim /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge +60`

```
bridge_parse_ports $INTERFACES | while read i
do
  for port in $i
  do
    # We attach and configure each port of the bridge
    if [ "$MODE" = "start" ] && [ ! -d /sys/class/net/$IFACE/brif/$port ]; then
      if [ -x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan ]; then
        env IFACE=$port /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
      fi
      if [ "$IF_BRIDGE_HW" ]
      then
         ifconfig $port down; ifconfig $port hw ether $IF_BRIDGE_HW
      fi
      if [ -f /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$port/disable_ipv6 ]
      then
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$port/disable_ipv6
      fi
      brctl addif $IFACE $port && ifconfig $port 0.0.0.0 up
```

It will probe if the ports are already members of a bridge, try to probe if it is a vlan interface by calling `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan`.

Basically, what was happening is that the `if [ -x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan ];` expression was never evaluated. "[True if FILE exists and is executable.](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)"